# Multipart messaging in .NET with service references c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, multipart, service-reference

I have looked for hours and haven't found an answer to what I would imagine is a somewhat common issue.

I have a lot of data (string[2000000]) that I want to send across to a service via a service reference (asmx).  SOAP blows up because of the size right now, and I dont want to increase the pipe because tomorrow it might be 4M strings to send.

So I was thinking multipart SOAP messages, however .NET doesn't natively support this (right?).  So how would one go about doing this?  Any help, or links would be greatly appreciated.

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] returnSameStringArray(string[] string_array)
{
    return string_array;
}
```

Calling Code:

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
basicHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 131072;

myServiceReference = new MyService.MyServiceSoapClient(basicHttpBinding, new EndpointAddress(@"http://myaddress/myservice.asmx"));
myServiceReference.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
myServiceReference.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

string[] theStringArray = new string[2000000](); //init with something later
theStringArray = myServiceReference.returnSameStringArray(theStringArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at zeromq and service stack. They give you the amount of control you need.

You could also look at splitting up your payload to multiple calls.

Comment: It is prefered not to break up the payload into multiple calls (the payload might change, or one of the strings could be a multi megabyte file parse, that would have to be split up anyways).  Thanks for the zeromq and service stack suggestion, I'll look into them now.

Comment: After getting a brief overview of zeromq, I dont understand how this would be implemented within the context of my code I have above.  I am relatively new to transports and networks, and maybe I just cant comprehend the necessity of zeromq with my current understanding.  Is there no multipart SOAP protocol I can use for this?  I have to use a third party protocol?

Comment: zeromq is great for large payloads and gives you a way to split them up to, leaving your business logic as is.